# ObjectOutputStream java баг

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Передаю в поток для записи `CopyOnWriteArrayList` (но как выяснилось значения это не имеет). Читаю с другого потока. Поток открывается на создании сокета подключения и закрывается по окончанию работы. Приложение представляет собой магазин. С киента делаю заказ - мне выводится список всех заказов, с моим в том числе(в конце списка). Делаю еще раз, и еще - список не меняется, хотя, на стороне сервера логи говорят об обратном - о том, что список заказов пополнился. Либо оно где-то кэшируется, или почему так происходит? Как это пофиксить?

Comment: Проблема из-за работы в  нескольких потоках скорее всего. И баг этот не в java, а в вашем коде

Comment: Понятно что у меня) Сервер получает соединение методом ```accept()``` и запускает отдельный класс, наследующий ```Runnable``` с помощью ```ExecutorService```. Этот класс в конструкторе принимает сокет и сам уже  себя открывает соединение. Но я подключалась пока только в одиночном экземпляре, странно тогда что список не обновляется. Да и обращению к серверу за списком нечастое, чтобы ```CopyOnWriteArrayList``` так подвисал

Comment: @Anastasiya добавьте свой код чтобы было от чего отталкиваться.